# How to create a matrix B from a matrix A using conditions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

If I have this matrix:

```
A:

X       Y       Z
1       1       2
0       3       4
0       5       6
2       7       8
7       9       10
8       11      12
3       13      14
12      14      16
15      17      18
```

How could I create new matrix B, C, D and E which contains:

```
B:
0       3       4
0       5       6

C: 
X       Y       Z
1       1       2 
2       7       8
3       13      14

D: 
7       9       10
8       11      12

E: 
12      14      16
15      17      18
```

The idea is to construct a loop asking if `0<A<1` else `1<A<5` else `6<A<10` else `11<A<15`. and create new matrix from that condition. Any idea about how to store the results of the loop?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable idea. Have you tried writing a script that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a loop, use [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) to achieve what you want.  Use the first column of `A` and check for the ranges that you want to look for, then use this to subset into the final matrix `A` to get what you want.

For example, to create the matrix `C`, find all locations in the first column of `A` that are between 1 and 5, then subset the matrix along the rows using these locations:

```
m = A(:,1) >= 1 & A(:,1) <= 5;
C = A(m,:);
```

You can repeat this in a similar way for the rest of the matrices you want to create.

Comment: rayryeng, do you have any advise about how to start to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48835464/how-to-manage-a-table-to-obtain-information-using-conditions

Comment: I don't know R so I wouldn't be able to help.

Comment: But, any idea using matlab or any software?, I'm looking for advise to open my mind and start to solve it.. I've been trying several times.. so it is ok if I can solve it using other language

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you an approach that uses the [discretize function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/discretize.html) in order to group the matrix rows into different categories based on their range. Here is the full implementation:

```
A = [
    1       1       2;
    0       3       4;
    0       5       6;
    2       7       8;
    7       9       10;
    8       11      12;
    3       13      14;
    12      14      16;
    15      17      18
];

A_range = [0 1 5 10 15];

bin_idx = discretize(A(:,1),A_range);
A_split = arrayfun(@(bin) A(bin_idx == bin,:),1:(numel(A_range) - 1),'UniformOutput',false);
celldisp(A_split);
```

Since you want to consider `5` different ranges based on the first column values, the arguments passed to `discretize` must be the first matrix column and a vector containing the group limits (first number inclusive left, second number exclusive right, second number inclusive left, third number exclusive right, and so on...). Since your ranges are a little bit messed up, feel free to adjust them to respect the correct output. The latter is returned in the form of a cell array of double matrices in which every element contains the rows belonging to a distinct group:

```
A_split{1} =

     0     3     4
     0     5     6

A_split{2} =

     1     1     2
     2     7     8
     3    13    14

A_split{3} =

     7     9    10
     8    11    12

A_split{4} =

    12    14    16
    15    17    18
```

Comment: Tommaso, do you have any advise about how to start to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48835464/how-to-manage-a-table-to-obtain-information-using-conditions

Comment: It's R, not Matlab. I've not being using it since quite long time.

Comment: Thanks Tommaso, but I could try it using matrixes in matlab.. I'm looking for an idea to open my mind an try again to solve it.. I know Matlab language as well..

Comment: OK, let me take a look :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, don't hesitate to ask me anything if the question is not clear. By the way, I've been trying with logical indexes.

Comment: I have a Matlab solution but if the OP doesn't add a matlab tag and declares he cal also accept a matlab based answer, I can't post it. Alternatively, open a similar question yourself.

Comment: Thanks Tommaso, I posted a solution in R of my question.. but im not happy with that. I opened the question to Matlab now, it would be great to receive your answer and give you the best solution. THANKS A LOT!